# sleuth + aws cloudwatch + spring boot microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, devops, spring-cloud-sleuth

I want to configure my spring boot microservice application with sleuth to send the logs to the cloud watch and track the requests using their trace ids generated by sleuth.

What are the ways i can achieve this

Comment: Are you using Fargate to deploy the springboot app?

Comment: nope not deploying anything this spring boot project is running on my local

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `spring-cloud-starter-aws-cloudwatch`.
You will need to be logged in in AWS of course and have permissions to create a logs stream and write logs.

IAM permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "CloudWatchLogsPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:logs:region:account-id:log-group:your-log-group:*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

with these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-cloudwatch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```